# use popen and argv[1] (name of the file)

Tags: c++

I want to use the name/path of the file opened by this code and trace its output by

`FILE* lsofFile_p = popen("c:\\adb install " + argv[1] , "r");`

and argv[1] this way gives error in building

Comment: What error in building do you get? What libraries are you referencing - what includes?

Comment: This is C code. Why the C++ tag? In C++ you have better options than using `FILE*`'s...

Comment: yes in the build not from libraries my libraries are #include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's essentially because you're trying to add a `char[]` array literal to a `char*` type: the compiler will not like that since the types don't match.

Writing `(std::string("c:\\adb install ") + argv[1]).c_str()` to concatenate your strings will fix it. This relies on *operator overloading* of `+` to a `std::string`, and `c_str()` extracts the character buffer. So, in full:

`FILE* lsofFile_p = popen((std::string("c:\\adb install ") + argv[1]).c_str(), "r");`

Do check the value of `argc` though before reading that element of `argv`.

Comment: thats also gives an error FILE* lsofFile_p = popen(std::string("c:\\adb install ") + argv[1]).c_str(); is it because of the "r" what is the meaning of it missing in the line

Comment: I've put the full text in that you need to type: you have your c_str() in the wrong place.

Comment: thank you so much, but well you please add a reference link than i can learn from it how to customize this code for example how i can use it with char array as it gives error in this line FILE* lsofFile_p = popen((std::string("c:\\adb connect ") + ip[20]).c_str, "r");
and the ip[20]=192.168.156.655:6985 for example

Comment: @DasserBasyouni: There's no substitute for a good book. I learnt from Stroustrup "The C++ Programming Language" and recommend you do the same. Make sure you get the C++11 version.